# Reduce the number of equations

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, polynomials

I have following 16 equations with 15 variables (XX is a variable, etc). I know there are only 6 independent variables. How can I reduce the number of equations below to get 9 independent equations?

```
2 x XX + 2 y YX + 2 z ZX == 2 X, 2 x XY + 2 y YY + 2 z ZY == 2 Y, 
2 x XZ + 2 y YZ + 2 z ZZ == 2 Z, 2 X XX + 2 XY Y + 2 XZ Z == 2 x, 
2 X YX + 2 Y YY + 2 YZ Z == 2 y, 2 X ZX + 2 Y ZY + 2 Z ZZ == 2 z, 
2 x X + 2 YZ ZY - 2 YY ZZ == 2 XX, 2 x Y - 2 YZ ZX + 2 YX ZZ == 2 XY, 
2 XZ == 2 x Z + 2 YY ZX - 2 YX ZY, 2 X y - 2 XZ ZY + 2 XY ZZ == 2 YX, 
2 y Y + 2 XZ ZX - 2 XX ZZ == 2 YY, 2 YZ == 2 y Z - 2 XY ZX + 2 XX ZY, 
2 XZ YY - 2 XY YZ + 2 X z == 2 ZX, -2 XZ YX + 2 XX YZ + 2 Y z == 2 ZY,
 2 XY YX - 2 XX YY + 2 z Z == 2 ZZ, x^2 + X^2 + XX^2 + XY^2 + XZ^2 + y^2 + Y^2 + YX^2 + YY^2 + YZ^2 + z^2 + Z^2 + ZX^2 + ZY^2 + ZZ^2 == 3
```

Comment: You could try `Reduce`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I tried, but it ran forever...

Comment: If you know which are the independent variables you could try `Eliminate`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't know which are independent variables. I only know how many...

Answer (score 5):

You can find variables to take as parameters by computing a Groebner basis after converting from equations to polynomials. The first polynomial will have seven variables, and we'll choose the six with the largest exponents to be parameters.

```
eqns = {2 x XX + 2 y YX + 2 z ZX == 2 X, 
   2 x XY + 2 y YY + 2 z ZY == 2 Y, 2 x XZ + 2 y YZ + 2 z ZZ == 2 Z, 
   2 X XX + 2 XY Y + 2 XZ Z == 2 x, 2 X YX + 2 Y YY + 2 YZ Z == 2 y, 
   2 X ZX + 2 Y ZY + 2 Z ZZ == 2 z, 2 x X + 2 YZ ZY - 2 YY ZZ == 2 XX,
    2 x Y - 2 YZ ZX + 2 YX ZZ == 2 XY, 
   2 XZ == 2 x Z + 2 YY ZX - 2 YX ZY, 
   2 X y - 2 XZ ZY + 2 XY ZZ == 2 YX, 
   2 y Y + 2 XZ ZX - 2 XX ZZ == 2 YY, 
   2 YZ == 2 y Z - 2 XY ZX + 2 XX ZY, 
   2 XZ YY - 2 XY YZ + 2 X z == 2 ZX, -2 XZ YX + 2 XX YZ + 2 Y z == 
    2 ZY, 2 XY YX - 2 XX YY + 2 z Z == 2 ZZ, 
   x^2 + X^2 + XX^2 + XY^2 + XZ^2 + y^2 + Y^2 + YX^2 + YY^2 + YZ^2 + 
     z^2 + Z^2 + ZX^2 + ZY^2 + ZZ^2 == 3};
polys = Subtract @@@ eqns;
Timing[gb = GroebnerBasis[polys];]
firstvars = Variables[gb[[1]]]
firstexpons = Map[Exponent[gb[[1]], #] &, firstvars]

(* Out[45]= {1.00765, Null}

Out[46]= {XZ, Y, YY, YZ, Z, ZY, ZZ}

Out[47]= {4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

Now compute another GB, this time over the field of rational functions in the parameters. We'll see that it contains 9 polynomials.

```
params = Most[firstvars];
vars = Complement[Variables[polys], params];
Timing[gb2 = 
   GroebnerBasis[polys, vars, CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions];]
gb2 // Length

(* Out[68]= {3.53252, Null}

Out[69]= 9 *)
```

It's a bit large, with leaf count near 6K. But here goes. But not unpostably large.

```
In[76]:= gb2

(* Out[76]= {-XZ^4 - XZ^2 Y^2 + XZ^2 YY^2 - XZ^2 YZ^2 + YY^2 YZ^2 - 
  2 Y YY YZ Z + XZ^2 Z^2 + Y^2 Z^2 + 
  XZ^2 ZY^2 + (2 YY YZ ZY - 2 Y Z ZY) ZZ + (-XZ^2 + 
     ZY^2) ZZ^2, -XZ^7 YY^2 - 2 XZ^5 YY^2 YZ^2 - XZ^3 YY^2 YZ^4 + 
  2 XZ^5 Y YY YZ Z + 2 XZ^3 Y YY YZ^3 Z - XZ^7 Z^2 - XZ^5 Y^2 Z^2 + 
  XZ^5 YY^2 Z^2 + XZ^7 YY^2 Z^2 + XZ^5 Y^2 YY^2 Z^2 - XZ^5 YY^4 Z^2 - 
  XZ^5 YZ^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 Y^2 YZ^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 + 
  2 XZ^5 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 Y^2 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 - 
  2 XZ^3 YY^4 YZ^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YY^2 YZ^4 Z^2 - XZ YY^4 YZ^4 Z^2 - 
  2 XZ^3 Y YY YZ Z^3 - 2 XZ^5 Y YY YZ Z^3 - 2 XZ^3 Y^3 YY YZ Z^3 + 
  4 XZ^3 Y YY^3 YZ Z^3 - 2 XZ^3 Y YY YZ^3 Z^3 + 4 XZ Y YY^3 YZ^3 Z^3 +
   XZ^5 Z^4 + XZ^7 Z^4 + XZ^3 Y^2 Z^4 + 2 XZ^5 Y^2 Z^4 + 
  XZ^3 Y^4 Z^4 - 2 XZ^5 YY^2 Z^4 - 2 XZ^3 Y^2 YY^2 Z^4 + 
  XZ^5 YZ^2 Z^4 + XZ^3 Y^2 YZ^2 Z^4 - 2 XZ^3 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^4 - 
  6 XZ Y^2 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^4 + 4 XZ^3 Y YY YZ Z^5 + 4 XZ Y^3 YY YZ Z^5 - 
  XZ^5 Z^6 - 2 XZ^3 Y^2 Z^6 - XZ Y^4 Z^6 + XZ^5 Y^2 ZY^2 + 
  2 XZ^5 YY^2 ZY^2 - XZ^5 Y^2 YY^2 ZY^2 + XZ^5 YZ^2 ZY^2 + 
  XZ^3 Y^2 YZ^2 ZY^2 - XZ^3 YY^2 YZ^2 ZY^2 - XZ^3 Y^2 YY^2 YZ^2 ZY^2 +
   XZ^3 YZ^4 ZY^2 - 3 XZ YY^2 YZ^4 ZY^2 + 4 XZ^3 Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 - 
  4 XZ^5 Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 - 2 XZ^3 Y^3 YY YZ Z ZY^2 + 
  4 XZ^3 Y YY^3 YZ Z ZY^2 + 6 XZ Y YY YZ^3 Z ZY^2 - 
  4 XZ^3 Y YY YZ^3 Z ZY^2 + 4 XZ Y YY^3 YZ^3 Z ZY^2 + 
  2 XZ^5 Z^2 ZY^2 - 3 XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + 2 XZ^5 Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + 
  2 XZ^3 Y^4 Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ^3 YY^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ^5 YY^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
  3 XZ^3 Y^2 YY^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ^5 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
  3 XZ Y^2 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + 2 XZ^3 Y^2 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + 
  3 XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - 11 XZ Y^2 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
  XZ^3 YZ^4 Z^2 ZY^2 + XZ YY^2 YZ^4 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
  6 XZ Y YY YZ Z^3 ZY^2 + 6 XZ^3 Y YY YZ Z^3 ZY^2 + 
  10 XZ Y^3 YY YZ Z^3 ZY^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ^3 Z^3 ZY^2 - XZ^3 Z^4 ZY^2 -
   XZ^5 Z^4 ZY^2 + 3 XZ Y^2 Z^4 ZY^2 - 4 XZ^3 Y^2 Z^4 ZY^2 - 
  3 XZ Y^4 Z^4 ZY^2 + XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^4 ZY^2 + XZ Y^2 YZ^2 Z^4 ZY^2 - 
  2 XZ^3 Y^2 ZY^4 + XZ^3 Y^4 ZY^4 - XZ^3 YY^2 ZY^4 + 
  XZ^3 Y^2 YY^2 ZY^4 - 2 XZ^3 YZ^2 ZY^4 - XZ Y^2 YZ^2 ZY^4 + 
  XZ^3 Y^2 YZ^2 ZY^4 + 3 XZ YY^2 YZ^2 ZY^4 - 3 XZ Y^2 YY^2 YZ^2 ZY^4 -
   XZ YZ^4 ZY^4 - 6 XZ Y YY YZ Z ZY^4 + 4 XZ^3 Y YY YZ Z ZY^4 + 
  6 XZ Y^3 YY YZ Z ZY^4 - XZ^3 Z^2 ZY^4 + 4 XZ Y^2 Z^2 ZY^4 - 
  2 XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 ZY^4 - 3 XZ Y^4 Z^2 ZY^4 + XZ YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^4 + 
  XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^4 + XZ Y^2 ZY^6 - XZ Y^4 ZY^6 + XZ YZ^2 ZY^6 - 
  XZ Y^2 YZ^2 ZY^6 + 
  ZX^2 (-XZ^5 YY^4 - 2 XZ^3 YY^4 YZ^2 - XZ YY^4 YZ^4 + 
     4 XZ^3 Y YY^3 YZ Z + 4 XZ Y YY^3 YZ^3 Z - 2 XZ^5 YY^2 Z^2 - 
     2 XZ^3 Y^2 YY^2 Z^2 - 2 XZ^3 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 - 
     6 XZ Y^2 YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 + 4 XZ^3 Y YY YZ Z^3 + 
     4 XZ Y^3 YY YZ Z^3 - XZ^5 Z^4 - 2 XZ^3 Y^2 Z^4 - XZ Y^4 Z^4 + 
     2 XZ^3 Y^2 YY^2 ZY^2 - 2 XZ^3 YY^2 YZ^2 ZY^2 - 
     2 XZ Y^2 YY^2 YZ^2 ZY^2 - 2 XZ YY^2 YZ^4 ZY^2 + 
     8 XZ^3 Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 + 4 XZ Y^3 YY YZ Z ZY^2 + 
     4 XZ Y YY YZ^3 Z ZY^2 - 2 XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
     2 XZ Y^4 Z^2 ZY^2 + 2 XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
     2 XZ Y^2 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ Y^4 ZY^4 - 2 XZ Y^2 YZ^2 ZY^4 - 
     XZ YZ^4 ZY^4) + 
  ZX (2 XZ^6 YY^3 + 4 XZ^4 YY^3 YZ^2 + 2 XZ^2 YY^3 YZ^4 - 
     6 XZ^4 Y YY^2 YZ Z - 6 XZ^2 Y YY^2 YZ^3 Z + 2 XZ^6 YY Z^2 + 
     2 XZ^4 Y^2 YY Z^2 + 2 XZ^4 YY YZ^2 Z^2 + 
     6 XZ^2 Y^2 YY YZ^2 Z^2 - 2 XZ^4 Y YZ Z^3 - 2 XZ^2 Y^3 YZ Z^3 - 
     2 XZ^4 Y^2 YY ZY^2 - 2 XZ^4 YY^3 ZY^2 + 2 XZ^4 YY YZ^2 ZY^2 + 
     2 XZ^2 Y^2 YY YZ^2 ZY^2 + 2 XZ^2 YY YZ^4 ZY^2 + 
     2 YY^3 YZ^4 ZY^2 - 4 XZ^4 Y YZ Z ZY^2 - 2 XZ^2 Y^3 YZ Z ZY^2 - 
     6 XZ^2 Y YY^2 YZ Z ZY^2 - 2 XZ^2 Y YZ^3 Z ZY^2 - 
     6 Y YY^2 YZ^3 Z ZY^2 - 2 XZ^4 YY Z^2 ZY^2 + 
     6 XZ^2 Y^2 YY Z^2 ZY^2 - 6 XZ^2 YY YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + 
     6 Y^2 YY YZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + 6 XZ^2 Y YZ Z^3 ZY^2 - 
     2 Y^3 YZ Z^3 ZY^2 + 2 XZ^2 Y^2 YY ZY^4 - 2 XZ^2 YY YZ^2 ZY^4 + 
     2 Y^2 YY YZ^2 ZY^4 + 2 YY YZ^4 ZY^4 + 4 XZ^2 Y YZ Z ZY^4 - 
     2 Y^3 YZ Z ZY^4 - 2 Y YZ^3 Z ZY^4) + 
  ZX (-2 XZ^4 YY^2 YZ ZY - 2 XZ^2 YY^2 YZ^3 ZY + 4 XZ^4 Y YY Z ZY + 
     4 XZ^2 Y YY YZ^2 Z ZY + 2 XZ^4 YZ Z^2 ZY - 
     2 XZ^2 Y^2 YZ Z^2 ZY - 2 XZ^2 Y^2 YZ ZY^3 + 
     2 XZ^2 YY^2 YZ ZY^3 - 2 XZ^2 YZ^3 ZY^3 + 2 YY^2 YZ^3 ZY^3 - 
     4 XZ^2 Y YY Z ZY^3 - 4 Y YY YZ^2 Z ZY^3 - 2 XZ^2 YZ Z^2 ZY^3 + 
     2 Y^2 YZ Z^2 ZY^3 + 2 Y^2 YZ ZY^5 + 
     2 YZ^3 ZY^5) ZZ + (2 XZ^5 YY YZ ZY + 2 XZ^3 YY YZ^3 ZY - 
     2 XZ^5 Y Z ZY - 2 XZ^5 Y YY^2 Z ZY - 2 XZ^3 Y YZ^2 Z ZY - 
     2 XZ^3 Y YY^2 YZ^2 Z ZY - 2 XZ^3 YY YZ Z^2 ZY - 
     2 XZ^5 YY YZ Z^2 ZY + 2 XZ^3 Y^2 YY YZ Z^2 ZY - 
     2 XZ^3 YY YZ^3 Z^2 ZY + 2 XZ^3 Y Z^3 ZY + 2 XZ^3 Y YZ^2 Z^3 ZY - 
     4 XZ^3 YY YZ ZY^3 + 2 XZ^3 Y^2 YY YZ ZY^3 - 2 XZ YY YZ^3 ZY^3 + 
     4 XZ^3 Y Z ZY^3 + 2 XZ^3 Y YY^2 Z ZY^3 + 2 XZ Y YZ^2 Z ZY^3 + 
     2 XZ^3 Y YZ^2 Z ZY^3 + 2 XZ Y YY^2 YZ^2 Z ZY^3 + 
     2 XZ YY YZ Z^2 ZY^3 + 2 XZ^3 YY YZ Z^2 ZY^3 - 
     2 XZ Y^2 YY YZ Z^2 ZY^3 + 2 XZ YY YZ^3 Z^2 ZY^3 - 
     2 XZ Y Z^3 ZY^3 - 2 XZ Y YZ^2 Z^3 ZY^3 + 2 XZ YY YZ ZY^5 - 
     2 XZ Y^2 YY YZ ZY^5 - 2 XZ Y Z ZY^5 - 
     2 XZ Y YZ^2 Z ZY^5) ZZ, -XZ^5 Y ZY - XZ^3 Y YZ^2 ZY - 
  2 XZ^3 YY YZ Z ZY - 2 XZ YY YZ^3 Z ZY + 3 XZ^3 Y Z^2 ZY + 
  2 XZ Y YZ^2 Z^2 ZY + 2 XZ YY YZ Z^3 ZY - 2 XZ Y Z^4 ZY + 
  2 XZ^3 Y ZY^3 + XZ Y YZ^2 ZY^3 + 2 XZ YY YZ Z ZY^3 - 
  3 XZ Y Z^2 ZY^3 - XZ Y ZY^5 + 
  ZX (XZ^4 Y YY ZY + XZ^2 Y YY YZ^2 ZY + XZ^4 YZ Z ZY + 
     XZ^2 YY^2 YZ Z ZY + XZ^2 YZ^3 Z ZY + YY^2 YZ^3 Z ZY - 
     2 XZ^2 Y YY Z^2 ZY - 2 Y YY YZ^2 Z^2 ZY - XZ^2 YZ Z^3 ZY + 
     Y^2 YZ Z^3 ZY - XZ^2 Y YY ZY^3 - Y YY YZ^2 ZY^3 - 
     XZ^2 YZ Z ZY^3 + Y^2 YZ Z ZY^3) + 
  z (-XZ^5 Z^2 - XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YY^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 + 
     XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z^3 + XZ^3 Z^4 + XZ Y^2 Z^4 - 
     XZ^3 Y^2 ZY^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 + XZ^3 Z^2 ZY^2 + 
     2 XZ Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + XZ Y^2 ZY^4) + 
  ZX (-XZ^4 YY Z - XZ^2 YY YZ^2 Z + XZ^2 Y YZ Z^2 + XZ^2 Y YZ ZY^2 + 
     XZ^2 YY Z ZY^2 + YY YZ^2 Z ZY^2 - Y YZ Z^2 ZY^2 - 
     Y YZ ZY^4) ZZ + (XZ^5 Z + XZ^3 YZ^2 Z - XZ^3 Z^3 - 
     2 XZ^3 Z ZY^2 - XZ YZ^2 Z ZY^2 + XZ Z^3 ZY^2 + XZ Z ZY^4) ZZ, 
 XZ^4 Y^2 ZY + 3 XZ^2 Y YY YZ Z ZY + XZ^4 Z^2 ZY - 2 XZ^2 Y^2 Z^2 ZY -
   XZ^2 YY^2 Z^2 ZY + XZ^2 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY + YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 ZY - 
  2 Y YY YZ Z^3 ZY - XZ^2 Z^4 ZY + Y^2 Z^4 ZY - XZ^2 Y^2 ZY^3 - 
  Y YY YZ Z ZY^3 - XZ^2 Z^2 ZY^3 + Y^2 Z^2 ZY^3 + 
  ZX (-XZ^3 Y^2 YY ZY - XZ^3 Y YZ Z ZY - 2 XZ Y YY^2 YZ Z ZY + 
     2 XZ Y^2 YY Z^2 ZY - 2 XZ YY YZ^2 Z^2 ZY + 2 XZ Y YZ Z^3 ZY + 
     XZ Y^2 YY ZY^3 + XZ Y YZ Z ZY^3) + 
  YX (XZ^5 Z^2 + XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 YY^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 - 
     XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 + 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z^3 - XZ^3 Z^4 - XZ Y^2 Z^4 + 
     XZ^3 Y^2 ZY^2 + 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 - XZ^3 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
     2 XZ Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ Y^2 ZY^4) + 
  ZX (XZ^3 Y YY Z + XZ^3 YZ Z^2 - XZ Y YY Z ZY^2 - 
     XZ YZ Z^2 ZY^2) ZZ + (-XZ^4 Y Z - XZ^2 YY YZ Z^2 + XZ^2 Y Z^3 + 
     2 XZ^2 Y Z ZY^2 + YY YZ Z^2 ZY^2 - Y Z^3 ZY^2 - Y Z ZY^4) ZZ, 
 XZ^5 YZ Z + XZ^3 Y^2 YZ Z - XZ^3 YY^2 YZ Z + XZ^3 YZ^3 Z - 
  XZ YY^2 YZ^3 Z + 2 XZ Y YY YZ^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 YZ Z^3 - XZ Y^2 YZ Z^3 + 
  XZ^3 Y YY ZY^2 - XZ^3 YZ Z ZY^2 + 2 XZ YY^2 YZ Z ZY^2 - 
  2 XZ Y YY Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ Y YY ZY^4 + 
  ZX (-XZ^4 YY YZ Z - XZ^2 Y^2 YY YZ Z + XZ^2 YY^3 YZ Z - 
     XZ^2 YY YZ^3 Z + YY^3 YZ^3 Z + XZ^4 Y Z^2 + XZ^2 Y^3 Z^2 - 
     XZ^2 Y YY^2 Z^2 + XZ^2 Y YZ^2 Z^2 - 3 Y YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 + 
     XZ^2 YY YZ Z^3 + 3 Y^2 YY YZ Z^3 - XZ^2 Y Z^4 - Y^3 Z^4 + 
     XZ^2 Y^3 ZY^2 - XZ^2 Y YY^2 ZY^2 + XZ^2 Y YZ^2 ZY^2 - 
     Y YY^2 YZ^2 ZY^2 - XZ^2 YY YZ Z ZY^2 + 2 Y^2 YY YZ Z ZY^2 - 
     Y^3 Z^2 ZY^2) + 
  y (-XZ^5 Z^2 - XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YY^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 + 
     XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z^3 + XZ^3 Z^4 + XZ Y^2 Z^4 - 
     XZ^3 Y^2 ZY^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 + XZ^3 Z^2 ZY^2 + 
     2 XZ Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + XZ Y^2 ZY^4) + 
  ZX (-XZ^2 Y YY YZ ZY + XZ^2 YY^2 Z ZY - XZ^2 YZ^2 Z ZY + 
     YY^2 YZ^2 Z ZY - 2 Y YY YZ Z^2 ZY + XZ^2 Z^3 ZY + Y^2 Z^3 ZY - 
     Y YY YZ ZY^3 + Y^2 Z ZY^3) ZZ + (XZ^3 Y YZ ZY - XZ^3 YY Z ZY - 
     XZ Y YZ ZY^3 + XZ YY Z ZY^3) ZZ, -XY XZ - YY YZ + Y Z - 
  ZY ZZ, -XZ^3 Y^2 YZ ZY + XZ^3 Y YY Z ZY - 2 XZ Y YY YZ^2 Z ZY + 
  2 XZ Y^2 YZ Z^2 ZY + 2 XZ YY^2 YZ Z^2 ZY - 2 XZ Y YY Z^3 ZY + 
  XZ Y^2 YZ ZY^3 - XZ Y YY Z ZY^3 + 
  ZX (XZ^2 Y^2 YY YZ ZY - XZ^2 Y YY^2 Z ZY + XZ^2 Y YZ^2 Z ZY + 
     Y YY^2 YZ^2 Z ZY - 2 XZ^2 YY YZ Z^2 ZY - 2 Y^2 YY YZ Z^2 ZY + 
     XZ^2 Y Z^3 ZY + Y^3 Z^3 ZY - Y^2 YY YZ ZY^3 + Y^3 Z ZY^3) + 
  XX (XZ^5 Z^2 + XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 YY^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 - 
     XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 + 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z^3 - XZ^3 Z^4 - XZ Y^2 Z^4 + 
     XZ^3 Y^2 ZY^2 + 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 - XZ^3 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
     2 XZ Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ Y^2 ZY^4) + (XZ^3 Y YZ Z - XZ^3 YY Z^2 - 
     XZ Y YZ Z ZY^2 + XZ YY Z^2 ZY^2) ZZ + 
  ZX (-XZ^2 Y YY YZ Z + XZ^4 Z^2 + XZ^2 Y^2 Z^2 + XZ^2 Y^2 ZY^2 + 
     Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 - XZ^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 - 
     Y^2 ZY^4) ZZ, -XZ^4 Y YY ZY - XZ^2 Y YY YZ^2 ZY - XZ^4 YZ Z ZY - 
  XZ^2 YY^2 YZ Z ZY - XZ^2 YZ^3 Z ZY - YY^2 YZ^3 Z ZY + 
  2 XZ^2 Y YY Z^2 ZY + 2 Y YY YZ^2 Z^2 ZY + XZ^2 YZ Z^3 ZY - 
  Y^2 YZ Z^3 ZY + XZ^2 Y YY ZY^3 + Y YY YZ^2 ZY^3 + XZ^2 YZ Z ZY^3 - 
  Y^2 YZ Z ZY^3 + 
  ZX (XZ^3 Y YY^2 ZY + XZ Y YY^2 YZ^2 ZY + 2 XZ^3 YY YZ Z ZY + 
     2 XZ YY YZ^3 Z ZY - XZ^3 Y Z^2 ZY - XZ Y^3 Z^2 ZY - 
     2 XZ Y YZ^2 Z^2 ZY - XZ Y^3 ZY^3 - XZ Y YZ^2 ZY^3) + 
  X (-XZ^5 Z^2 - XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YY^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 + 
     XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z^3 + XZ^3 Z^4 + XZ Y^2 Z^4 - 
     XZ^3 Y^2 ZY^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 + XZ^3 Z^2 ZY^2 + 
     2 XZ Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + XZ Y^2 ZY^4) + 
  ZX (-XZ^3 YY^2 Z - XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z + 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z^2 - XZ^3 Z^3 - 
     XZ Y^2 Z^3 + 2 XZ Y YY YZ ZY^2 - XZ Y^2 Z ZY^2 + 
     XZ YZ^2 Z ZY^2) ZZ + (XZ^4 YY Z + XZ^2 YY YZ^2 Z - 
     XZ^2 Y YZ Z^2 - XZ^2 Y YZ ZY^2 - XZ^2 YY Z ZY^2 - 
     YY YZ^2 Z ZY^2 + Y YZ Z^2 ZY^2 + Y YZ ZY^4) ZZ, 
 XZ^6 Z + XZ^4 Y^2 Z - XZ^4 YY^2 Z + XZ^4 YZ^2 Z - XZ^2 YY^2 YZ^2 Z + 
  2 XZ^2 Y YY YZ Z^2 - XZ^4 Z^3 - XZ^2 Y^2 Z^3 - XZ^2 Y YY YZ ZY^2 - 
  2 XZ^4 Z ZY^2 + XZ^2 YY^2 Z ZY^2 - XZ^2 YZ^2 Z ZY^2 - 
  YY^2 YZ^2 Z ZY^2 + 2 Y YY YZ Z^2 ZY^2 + XZ^2 Z^3 ZY^2 - 
  Y^2 Z^3 ZY^2 + Y YY YZ ZY^4 + XZ^2 Z ZY^4 - Y^2 Z ZY^4 + 
  x (-XZ^5 Z^2 - XZ^3 Y^2 Z^2 + XZ^3 YY^2 Z^2 - XZ^3 YZ^2 Z^2 + 
     XZ YY^2 YZ^2 Z^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z^3 + XZ^3 Z^4 + XZ Y^2 Z^4 - 
     XZ^3 Y^2 ZY^2 - 2 XZ Y YY YZ Z ZY^2 + XZ^3 Z^2 ZY^2 + 
     2 XZ Y^2 Z^2 ZY^2 + XZ Y^2 ZY^4) + 
  ZX (-XZ^5 YY Z - XZ^3 Y^2 YY Z + XZ^3 YY^3 Z - XZ^3 YY YZ^2 Z + 
     XZ YY^3 YZ^2 Z - 2 XZ Y YY^2 YZ Z^2 + XZ^3 YY Z^3 + 
     XZ Y^2 YY Z^3 + XZ^3 Y YZ ZY^2 + XZ^3 YY Z ZY^2 + 
     2 XZ YY YZ^2 Z ZY^2 - 2 XZ Y YZ Z^2 ZY^2 - XZ Y YZ ZY^4) + 
  ZX (-XZ^3 Y YY ZY - XZ^3 YZ Z ZY + XZ Y YY ZY^3 + 
     XZ YZ Z ZY^3) ZZ + (XZ^4 Y ZY + XZ^2 YY YZ Z ZY - 
     XZ^2 Y Z^2 ZY - 2 XZ^2 Y ZY^3 - YY YZ Z ZY^3 + Y Z^2 ZY^3 + 
     Y ZY^5) ZZ} *)
```

Comment: +1 for this approach.

Comment: Your code contains `GroebnerBasis[polys]`, which is inconsistent with the documentation and, according to the Mathematica frontend, is missing an argument.  Nonetheless, it works., although it produces a different result from `GroebnerBasis[polys, Variables[polys]];`. Can you provide an explanation, or would you prefer that I post a question, so that your explanation has more visibility?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey This is an uncommon case where I don't know what variable order to use, so I let GB choose. I probably should have added `Sort->True` (and specified the variables in the way you suggest). Though that can backfire, since the heuristics behind this sorting are fallible.

Answer (score 4):

The following provides a solution to the sixteen equations for nine dependent variables in terms of six independent variables, and from this the desired nine equations can be obtained.  With the sixteen equations designated `eqs`,

```
s = Solve[eqs, {YZ, x, X, YY, Y, z, XY, XZ, y}]
```

produces a result in several minutes.  With

```
s // Dimensions
(* {4, 9} *)
s // LeafCount
(* 1550453 *)
```

it is far too large to reproduce here.  The nine corresponding equations follow immediately from any of the four solution sets, for instance.

```
First[s] /. Rule -> Equal
```

Whether this ponderous result is of any practical value is unclear to me.

The obvious question to ask is, why choose to solve for `{YZ, x, X, YY, Y, z, XY, XZ, y}` from among some 5000 other possibilities.  In fact, it was by trial and error.  I found a readily solvable set after only a few tries, suggesting that the set of six independent variables is not at all unique.